# Declaring handler and handling errors with a similar approach to after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I'm looking to record errors from a handful of objects into a db table, let's say "errs".

Ideally I'd like to declare it so as it can be added to the object definition ins a similar manner to "validate" or "attr_accessible". For example:

```
def SomeObject

    validate: :someMember

    on_error: :someCallback

    def someMethod

    end
end
```

Where would I begin implementing something of this nature or alternatively is there a commonly accepted method for doing this type of thing?

To expand a bit:

Say I parse a file whose contents define an ActiveRecord extension (ActiveRecord::MyClass) and one of the following errors occur.

```
1. Type mismatch: self.someMember is STRING, expected BOOLEAN.
2. File badly formatted. Some line isn't formatted as expected.
3. Validation failed (ActiveRecord)
```

On these errors I'd like to record these using the directive type syntax that is found (typically) at the top of an object definition.

Comment: Do you mean validation errors?

Comment: not clear enough. are you looking for [Observer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers)?

Comment: Yes, I think the extra handling I'd been including in this group should be handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for an [Observer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).  Make an observer for your class, then use the `after_validation` [active record callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) to run the code that records your errors.